# Django - HTML Select not staying selected

Tags: django

I am trying to keep the selected object selected in html after submitting form.

Below is my view and html select form.

Tried all solutions on stack overflow and all combinations when referring to object in template and making changes to my view, but no success in keeping the selected object selected.

views.py

```
def profile(request,pk):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True, owner=request.user)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_owner=request.user)
    filter_post = request.GET.get('filter_post')

    if filter_post:
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_owner=request.user, post__exact=filter_post)
        ### Tried post_id, post__id, instead of post__exact

    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'posts':posts, 'comments':comments, 'filter_post':filter_post})
```

profile.html

```
<form method="GET">
    <select class="form-select"  id="filter_post" name='filter_post'>
        <option value=""{% if value == "" %}selected {% endif %}>
            Select post
        </option>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <option value="{{post.id}}" {% if post.id == filter_post %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>
                {{post.title}} - {{post.created}}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `{% if value == "" %}selected {% endif %}` value is not passed into the context. So, if that equation comes true, you will get selected attribute in two different option in a select.

Comment: added it this way but still no change:

filter_post = request.GET.get('filter_post', '')

Answer (score 0):

@moddayjob seems to be right, you don't have any `value` passed to that context. Moreover, it doesn't look like you need it. I believe if you replace this:

```py
{% if value == "" %}
```

with this:

```py
{% if filter_post == None %}
```

it will work correctly.

Comment: Still not working, however thanks for the suggestion